# gprc demo by go and python

Tags: python, go, grpc

I want to get a Grpc demo which client is Golang and server is Python. I use Grpc official code as my demo, but it's doesn't work. Can someone help me?

If I generate the client and server by same language, example: Python or Golang. It works correctly.

1. helloworld.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

2.get relevant code

1) get python relevant code:
python -m grpc_tools.protoc --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. -I. helloworld.proto

2) get go relevant code:
protoc -I . helloworld.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:.

3. helloworld_grpc_server.py

```py
import time
import logging
import grpc
from concurrent import futures

import helloworld_pb2
import helloworld_pb2_grpc

_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24


class Greeter(helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):

    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)


def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    helloworld_pb2_grpc.add_GreeterServicer_to_server(Greeter(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
    server.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    serve()
```

4. greeter_client/main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"

    pb "demo/grpc/go_python/helloworld"
)

const (
    address     = "localhost:50051"
    defaultName = "world"
)

func main() {
    // Set up a connection to the server.
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    c := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)

    // Contact the server and print out its response.
    name := defaultName
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        name = os.Args[1]
    }
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    r, err := c.SayHello(ctx, &pb.HelloRequest{Name: name})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not greet: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Greeting: %s", r.Message)
}
```

5. run the demo

```
server:
python helloworld_grpc_server.py

client:
go run main.go
```

But, I get the wrong output for client:

```
2019/08/07 19:18:03 could not greet: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = Method not found!
exit status 1
```

I expect to the demo work.

Comment: I can't see an obvious problem but usually this means some namespacing issue of the server. Try running `grpc_cli ls localhost:50051` and see how the service is registered, perhaps the package name in the Go code is different somehow?

Comment: I solve my problem now. Because I generate python grpc code with wrong helloworld.proto which omit one line: `package helloworld;`.

Comment: ah, so my instinct was right :) you might want to phrase that as an answer for people having similar problems.

Comment: But, according to my demo result, if I use python as both grpc server and grpc client, helloworld.proto don't need the line: `package helloworld;` But if I use go as grpc client, I need the line:  `package helloworld;` to generate python grpc code. That's confused. :(